# How to upload wordpress post thumbnail manually [ wp_database ]

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, file-upload

I'm trying to create an external php script outside of wordpress to manage posts in a custom backoffice (using Symfony2).

So far everything works fine. I just want to know how to set a post thumbnail manually by uploading a picture and registering its informations directly into Wordpress database, means :

- Which upload dir to use
- Which post type
- post status
- The maining of postMime
- Metas to add
- ...etc

In general I just want to know how to register a post thumbnail manually without using Wordpress functions.

Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't be better off using something like WordPress's XMLRPC interface for this? Throwing stuff directly into WordPress's database will be quite fragile, I'd have thought. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840797/how-can-i-add-a-thumbnail-to-a-wordpress-post-using-xmlrpclib-python-library

Comment: I agree, mixing frameworks unless it's absolutely necessary is terrible idea...

Comment: I'm not doing everything in my way, I'm using https://github.com/kayue/KayueWordpressBundle which is a Symfony2 bundle to connect Sf to WP, But I cant find a complete documentation.

I've already posted a question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003509/where-can-i-find-a-complete-documentation-of-the-symfony2-bundle-kayuewordpressb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you must create manually the postmeta **_wp_attachment_metadata** which is a serialized array.

1. First you get your thumbnail:

$file = $form->getData();
$thumb = $file['logo'];

1. you get your thumbnail characteristics (width, height...):

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($thumb);

1. building the array from the thumb charactéristics:

   $meta_data_value = array();
    $meta_data_value['width'] = $width;
    $meta_data_value['height'] = $height;
    $meta_data_value['file'] = $slug.'.'.$ext;

   $sizes = array();
    $sizes['thumbnail'] = array('file' => $slug.'.'.$ext,'width' => 125,'height' => 150,'mime-type' => $mime);
    $sizes['medium'] = array('file' => $slug.'.'.$ext,'width' => 250,'height' => 300,'mime-type' => $mime);
    $meta_data_value['sizes'] = $sizes;
    $meta_data_value['image_meta'] = array('aperture' => 0,'credit' => '','camera' => '','caption' => '','created_timestamp' => 0,'copyright' => '','focal_length' => 0,'iso' => 0,'shutter_speed' => 0,'title' => '');
    $meta_data_value = serialize($meta_data_value);

   1. Finally adding the postmeta with Doctrine :

      $meta_data = new PostMeta();
      $meta_data->setKey('_wp_attachment_metadata');
      $meta_data->setValue($meta_data_value);
      $meta_data->setPost($logo);// supposing that you create the post $logo
      $em->persist($meta_data);
      $em->flush();